# Communication of 2 APIs on different networks

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, api, express

I am looking for a way to transmit the elements of my database, from my API which is on a Raspberry Pi to another API located in another network.
The two APIs are both coded in javascript.

Thank you in advance for your help.

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const dataRouter = require('./routes/data');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true,
  })
);

app.use(function(req,res,next){
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","http://localhost:8080");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","Origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept");
  next();
}),

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.json({'message': 'ok'});
})

app.use('/data', dataRouter);

/* Error handler middleware */
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  const statusCode = err.statusCode || 500;
  console.error(err.message, err.stack);
  res.status(statusCode).json({'message': err.message});


  return;
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
});
```

Comment: If there's no network route between them then it's irrelevant what the code is. Once you have a route between the machines, then a standard http request would work.

Comment: The idea actually corresponds to what I want to do (I had in mind to make an HTTP request) but the problem is that I do not know how to go about creating the route you are telling me about.

Comment: We'd need to know more about the networks you're talking about. You probably need to open a port in a firewall or router somewhere at the edge of the target network. But how you do that, how easy it is, and what the security implications would be, depend on a lot of other factors. For simple home networks protected by NAT you could use port forwarding. For other networks, it maybe a lot more complex. Your other option of course is to host the target API on an internet-facing server to begin with. But again...security, privacy, cost etc, we know nothing about your requirements or constraints

Comment: This is, to a very large extent, not a programming problem. It's a network / architecture issue.

Comment: @ADyson I don't understand what you are trying to tell me but for your information the destination API is well connected to the internet. At the moment I am not concerned with the security of this transmission but only looking for a way to make it work.

Comment: Do you understand what a firewall does? A computer (or whole network) can have an open outbound connection to the internet, but a firewall can restrict incoming connections from other computers - to stop hacking attempts etc. So you may be able to connect to the internet from the destination API but that doesn't mean that others can connect to it. If the destination API can listen on a public IP address then you should have no problems generally, but if it can't then you need to work out how to make a route to it. Like I said, we can't give specific advice without knowing the network topology